# How are basis defined in non-linear coordinate systems?

Tags: functional-analysis, manifolds

A basis is defined as follows:

`Given a basis of a vector space V, every element of V can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of basis vectors, whose coefficients are referred to as vector coordinates or components.`

How does this work if we have some non-linear manifold? What is the basis of that coordinate system? This definition doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: If your manifold is over $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ then you have a basis in each neighbhorhood of your manifold using the chart

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** have a "basis" for any thing that isn't a linear space.  But, as Tony S.F. said, you can define the "tangent space" of a differentiable manifold and define a basis for that.

Comment: Fascinating. So we take the tangent plane at every point and define a basis for each of those? That's amazing.